# Multiple instances of httpcontext.current.cache

Tags: caching, c#-4.0, wcf-data-services

I am caching two bits of data in my WCF Data Service using the httpcontext.current.cache. It makes sense to store them both using the same key (the client id) but the type of data is different and the expiration rules should be different. So, I was wondering if it was possible to create two instances of  httpcontext.current.cache? Or, alternatively, if there is a more appropriate way to do this?

Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the ClientId appended with a key that will tell you which of the two pieces of data you're looking at.  Something like "ClientId-Data1" and "ClientId-Data2".

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. That is essentially what I am doing. I guess that means creating two instances is not possible?

Comment: I think it would be very difficult and not desirable.  Glad to be of service.